# TrySetWallpaperImageAsync not working in latest Insider build?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

Since the latest Insider build (14352) TrySetWallpaperImageAsync/TrySetLockScreenImageAsync does not work anymore. It was working fine before. Did the API change? The method returns false, but `UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.IsSupported()`
returns true.

I am downloading images from Unsplash and saving them to `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` Here is my code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Ok)
{
    var imageFile = await  ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        await response.Content.WriteToStreamAsync(stream);
    }
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
    UserProfilePersonalizationSettings settings = UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current;
    await settings.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(file);
}
```

There are no errors and the image is saved to the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,After my research what I found is that the api isn't working on the insider builds of the Windows.I have an another laptop which isn't on the insider program and the same code to set the wallpaper works fine :D
I did report this problem on the feedback hub.Hope you do the same and all we can do is wait for a fix